# GPS tracking device

Tags: privacy, tools

Could anyone please tell me if there exists a GPS tracking device that is light, small and safe (e.g., does not cause harmful radiation) and can be tracked back via say an app on a phone?

Comment: It would help if you defined what you meant by a "GPS tracking device".  A device that uses GPS to track where the device has been?  A device to figure out someone else's location?  And what do you mean by "tracked back"?  What devices have you looked at so far, and what research have you already done?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that tracking someone without their explicit permission is an invasion of privacy and illegal, regardless of the legal status existing between the persons (child, parent, significant other, friend). Once the invasion of privacy is found out (and it usually is), it will cause mental damage to the person whose privacy is being invaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a GPS device to be [pretty small](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9566), but that's not all there is to it. You also need to *transmit* your GPS location. So that means some sort of communcation spec; Bluetooth, WiFi, or more likely cell phone.

OK, so you get your GPS module, a [controller chip](http://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy3.html), and a [cellular module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10138). Now what? Perhaps you could send a text message every 5 minutes with your current location? Or perhaps connect via cellular Internet and ping a website somewhere with your current location. Either way, you need a cell plan, which means paying a monthly fee to your compatible carrier of choice.

Of course, it'd be simpler just to use an old cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

Garmin currently makes a unit called the GTU 10. If you're willing to shell out some dough, you can buy this unit and get the free Garmin Tracker app on your smartphone. The app lets you set up geofences and maintains tracking history.

I've used this combination and found it to be fairly useful, but it can have trouble locating satellites indoors, near tall buildings, or in a dense forest.